# AEM 6.1 - Memory leak by Jackrabbit Oak

Tags: java, memory-leaks, aem, jackrabbit, jackrabbit-oak

I'm using AEM 6.1 with JR 2.10 and JR Oak 1.2
All system is working well until I run a job which inserts a huge of content and publish them  automatically.
After that, content updating is really slow and sometimes makes the server down.
This is the log:

> 04.08.2017 10:15:43.014 DEBUG [172.12.34.37 [1501812943013] POST /bin/receive HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.replication.impl.content.durbo.DurboImporter Received new durbo request on path: /content/…
> 04.08.2017 10:15:43.015 DEBUG [172.12.34.37 [1501812943013] POST /bin/receive HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.replication.impl.content.durbo.DurboImporter Starting node creation for durbo request on path: /content/...
> 04.08.2017 10:15:43.015 DEBUG [172.12.34.37 [1501812943013] POST /bin/receive HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.replication.impl.content.durbo.DurboImporter writeback content…
> 04.08.2017 10:15:43.573 DEBUG [172.12.34.37 [1501812943013] POST /bin/receive HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.replication.impl.content.durbo.DurboImporter restore sibling order…
> 04.08.2017 10:15:50.946 DEBUG [172.12.34.37 [1501812943013] POST /bin/receive HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.replication.impl.content.durbo.DurboImporter restore children order…
> 04.08.2017 10:15:50.946 DEBUG [172.12.34.37 [1501812943013] POST /bin/receive HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.replication.impl.content.durbo.DurboImporter saving…
> 04.08.2017 10:18:10.177 INFO [172.12.34.37 [1501812943013] POST /bin/receive HTTP/1.1] com.day.cq.replication.impl.content.durbo.DurboImporter imported content in 147163ms for durbo request on path: /content/...

Here is the memory graph from the CloudWatch:
[CloudWatch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxjMY.jpg)

There are 3 times the memory goes down: 1 time I did the compaction and 2 times later I restarted the server.

And the report from Memory Analysis:

[Memory Analysis part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjzw7.png)

Do you guys have any idea about this?
Thank you guys so much in advance.

Comment: Maybe the total content is now the limiting factor.

Comment: Actually, each time the cron job runs, it removes all the old content first after that inserts all the new one.

Comment: All service packs installed? What is the exact Oak version?

Comment: @JulianReschke I'm using AME 6.1 SP2, JR version 2.10 and JR Oak version 1.2

Comment: What is the *exact* Oak version?